# The recyclerView items doesnt shows up when i put them inside a horizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i want to create a table of informations using firestore and recyclerView but the informations are larger than the screen width so i tried using horizontalScrollView, the header of the table looks fine when i added the scroll but the recyclerView items gone (when i remove the scroll the recycler works fine) the first code xml is for the fragement and the second xml is for the recyclerView item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tableFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flockText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="flock 1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flockText">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/table_bg"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/day"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Chicken number"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mortality"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Mortality"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mortalityTot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Total mortality"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/food"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Food consumption"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tableFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/flockText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="flock 1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flockText">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5">

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/table_bg"
                        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/day"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/Number"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Chicken number"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mortality"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Mortality"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mortalityTot"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Total mortality"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/food"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_column="1"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                            android:paddingVertical="6dp"
                            android:text="Food consumption"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```